# typescript type definition for global libraries

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a problem with types in ts.

I have load some global libraries in index.html file
and I want to use them in my main.ts

I can not install the library from npm to use it's built in definition and there is no definitions for it in @types package.

How can I introduce my own .d.ts file as it's definition?

I had tried `/// <reference path="path/to/file/myModule.d.ts"/>` and in that file I have something like this

```
declare namespace X {
...
...
}
```

but when in main.ts file i want to use X.type as a type it will make error

> TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'X'.

What should I do?

Comment: This document helped for me: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html) and this: [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21344)

Answer (score 1):

You can set own directory with type definitions in `tsconfig.json` eg. `typings` directory:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "typeRoots" : ["./node_modules/@types", "./typings"]
   }
}
```

If you set `typeRoots` property in config, `node_modules/@types` (which is by default) won't be taken into account so that's why you should set those two in array

Comment: and where should I put my own declare file to be recognized? I had made typings directory and add my declare file into it. but it didn't be recognized? should I do import it someway?

Comment: But did you put that option I described above into `tsconfig.json` ?